# NestJs Sequelize connecting to multiple DB to same model

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I am trying to connect to two separate DBs but to the **same model** named **Period**, here is my main module where I set up two separate connections:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import Period from './models/period.model';

@Module({
  imports: [
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      name: 'alpha',
      dialect: 'postgres',
      port: 5432,
      password: 'werwer',
      database: 'postgres',
      username: 'postgres',
      host: 'localhost',
      models: [Period],
      autoLoadModels: true,
      synchronize: false,
      logging: false,
    }),
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      name: 'external',
      dialect: 'postgres',
      port: 5432,
      password: 'test-password',
      database: 'postgres',
      username: 'test_external_db_username',
      host: 'test_external_db_host',
      models: [Period],
      autoLoadModels: true,
      synchronize: false,
      logging: false,
    }),
    SequelizeModule.forFeature([Period], 'external'),
    SequelizeModule.forFeature([Period], 'alpha'),
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I am trying to use those two connections to fetch data from two separate dbs `app.service.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import Period from './models/period.model';

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Period, 'external')
    private readonly externalPeriodModel: typeof Period,
    @InjectModel(Period, 'alpha')
    private readonly periodModel: typeof Period,
  ) {
    this.testMethod();
  }

  public async testMethod() {
    const periods = await this.periodModel.findAll();

    console.log('@periods');
    console.log(periods);

    const externalPeriods = await this.externalPeriodModel.findAll();

    console.log('@externalPeriods');
    console.log(externalPeriods);
  }
}
```

The problem is that I get the data from only one db with both requests. And I want to be able to connect to separate DBs through the same model. The reason for it is that I want to create a script that would copy data from external db into my local db.

Thanks in advance for your time!

=== EDIT

I have tried connecting to different Sequelize models (connect to `Period` model from `alpha` db, and connect to `SomeOtherModel` model from `external` db), and it worked, but I can't make it connect to the same model from different databases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could take a look at "Multiple databases" section in Sequelize section in the nestjs documentation https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database

Not sure if this could work for your specific case.

Comment: I have tried it but no success sadly.

Comment: did you try to inject multiple times sequelize  in your service ?
@InjectConnection('name1')
private sequelize1: Sequelize,

@InjectConnection('name2')
private sequelize2: Sequelize,

Comment: This one works, thanks! But interacting through models, and not through sequelize instance would much more convenient.

Comment: No problems
Yes I understand but it seems impossible to work with models directly

Comment: Can you share an example of what worked for you ? As I can't find InjectConnection as mentioned in a Jacky's comment and also InjectDataSource in nestjs docs. 
Thanks